# Simplifying radical expression $\sqrt[4]{3x}\cdot\sqrt{y+4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I've never been any good with radicals...
$$\sqrt[4]{3x}\cdot\sqrt{y+4}$$
Can anyone help with simplifying? Can I just square the inside of the first radical and then just multiply the two resulting square roots?
Edit: Apparently this is the answer

> $$\dfrac1{25x^4}$$

Comment: Is this too easy or something?

Comment: You could write it as $$\sqrt[4]{x}\cdot\sqrt[4]{3}\cdot\sqrt{y+4}$$but I'm not too sure if that's considered "simplified".

Comment: @Frank Apparently you can convert either the first term into a square root or the second term into a (quartic?) root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iam not so sure about it

$\sqrt[4]{3x}\cdot\sqrt{y+4}$  be  A

Then $A^4= 3x(y^2+16+8y) $

Simplifying $A^4$ we get

$3xy^2+ 48x+24xy=A^4$

Then  A= $ \sqrt[4]{ 3xy^2+ 48x+24xy}$

Is it ok

Comment: Check the edit to my question. Do you know how to get the answer?

Comment: Ok then i must be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can write $\sqrt{\sqrt{3x}(y+4)}$ or $\sqrt[4]{3}\sqrt{\sqrt{x}(y+4)}$

Comment: More clarification?

Comment: Now I see that you have reputation 3000+. I don't see what's your goal with asking such question.

Comment: High rep doesn't necessarily mean better at math; this question serves as proof of that...=(

Comment: so do you know how to get the answer?

Comment: I don't see how y can disappear